# Javascript: Extract keypair value in array using values from second array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a shortlist array that I wish to use to extract the numerical value for the corresponding months from the seasons array.

```
var shortlist = [ "dec", "jan", "feb" ];

var seasons = [{ "jan": "0", "feb": "0", "mar": "0", "apr": "0", "may": "2", "jun": "1", "jul": "1", "aug": "1", "sep": "2", "oct": "0", "nov": "0", "dec": "0" }];
```

As each value is extracted it will be used for some additional functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var shortlist = [ "dec", "jan", "feb" ];

var seasons = [{ "jan": "0", "feb": "0", "mar": "0", "apr": "0", "may": "2", "jun": "1", "jul": "1", "aug": "1", "sep": "2", "oct": "0", "nov": "0", "dec": "0" }];


const result = shortlist.map(e => +seasons[0][e] || 0);

console.log(result);
```

But if you have multiple objects in `seasons` array, try it like this, it will give you nested arrays:

```js
var shortlist = [ "dec", "jan", "feb" ];

var seasons = [
  { "jan": "0", "feb": "0", "mar": "0", "apr": "0", "may": "2", "jun": "1", "jul": "1", "aug": "1", "sep": "2", "oct": "0", "nov": "0", "dec": "0" },
  { "jan": "2", "feb": "0", "mar": "0", "apr": "0", "may": "2", "jun": "1", "jul": "0", "aug": "1", "sep": "0", "oct": "0", "nov": "0", "dec": "1" },
];


const result = seasons.map(s => shortlist.map(e => +s[e] || 0));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var shortlist = ['dec', 'jan', 'feb'];

var seasons = [
  {
    jan: '0',
    feb: '0',
    mar: '0',
    apr: '0',
    may: '2',
    jun: '1',
    jul: '1',
    aug: '1',
    sep: '2',
    oct: '0',
    nov: '0',
    dec: '0'
  }
];

const nums = shortlist.map((mon) => seasons[0][mon]);
console.log(nums);
```